# evaporator circuit problem with BU407 overheating

Tags: circuit-analysis

Using the standard circuit from YouTube but the mist is not at all efficient and I’m burning out transistors on overheating. Where am I going wrong, please?

I purchased the components locally from a specialty shop.

Kindly see attached circuits tried. Both give a very high heating of the BU407 (to destruction).

Below are the images of the various circuits tried:

1st Image (Imagination)
https://youtu.be/HGfFsQ3viwk

[image: schematic 1]

The second comes from https://youtu.be/7XEkeVaJEFQ
where I tried this one with 4.1K and 120 Ohms and replaced the 4.1 with 3.3K and the 120 Ohm with 100 Ohm, both did not give efficiency, but noted that the current requirement dropped slightly when the 4.1K resistance used.

[image: schematic 2]

I also tried various inductance values ranging from 18 to 60 micro Henry still with no luck...

The real issue here is two fold:

- a) the BU 407 very much overheating despite the sink size (the same goes for BU406 and TIP 41CV transistors.
- b) the efficiency of the vapor is very much missing.... I'm using a 25mm ceramic disk marked BT86.

I'm a mechanical engineer as well as a petroleum engineer, hence my experiance with electronics is slim, particularly as I graduated in 1980 where they were hardly any real electronics around.

I would appreciate if someone could suggest what I should be changing in any of the circuits presented, else If anyone can suggest a different simple similar circuit that I can try.

I have added two pictures for my circuit used (front and back)

[image]

[image]

Comment: your problem is `Using the standard circuit from YouTube` ... for one, there is no such thing as `standard circuit` ... secondly, do not take youtube videos as being accurate

Comment: You need to provide more explicit information. There’s many kinds of evaporators and zillions of YouTube vids. Helps us to help you.

Comment: I had added two schematics and an explanation of what I did if you kindly can look into them...